# What do native speakers call this home decoration item?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

[image]

String curtain? Or string curtains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In British English they are definitely called *string curtains*. Use the plural 'curtains' when it is a pair, and the singular 'curtain' when it is a single piece. Note, however, they are not that common in Britain and not everybody would know what to call them.

Used the way they are in your picture they may also be called a '*room divider*', although this is an umbrella term that also describes solid furniture used to 'divide' an open-plan room into two areas.

Comment: Then, should I say “room dividers”?

Comment: @Iloveeverybody so long as you don't think that is ambiguous. If you pointed at the curtain dividing your room and asked "do you like my room divider?" then people would know what you meant. If you suddenly said "I'm going to buy a room divider" without any context, people might think you mean a piece of wooden furniture.

Comment: The picture in the question shows a single item being used on undivided doorway. There "is a string curtain" hanging in the doorway not there "are string curtains". Use of the plural is strictly wrong. Even if that was not a 90cm wide product but two 45cm wide products, there would still be a "two panel string curtain". Even a two piece divided curtain used on the theatre stage is properly a curtain, not curtains.

Comment: @Smartybartfast Then you should also downvote the accepted answer, because that says he can see a pair.

Comment: @Smartybartfast What makes me laugh is that I upvoted one of your answers this morning in which you begged people not to downvote because you said "lower class". You obviously know how hypercritical and unreasonable certain people here can be, yet you jump to downvote my answer rather than give constructive comments to help improve it.

Comment: @Astralbee I upvoted you because you at least tried hard to help me!

Answer (score 2):

I think they are a pair of curtains. It looks like they are divided at the top into two pieces in this design.

However with string curtains like these, the fact that they are constructed in two pieces is not so important. So both "a string curtain" and "string curtains" would probably be used.

String curtains like this are rather rare. More common would be curtains with beads on strings, called bead or beaded curtains.